# How to dynamically update header title in Ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Following are my routes -

```
  .state('profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
  })  
  .state('profile.basics', {
    url: '/profile-basics',
    views: {
      'profileContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/profile-basics.html',
        controller: 'profileCtrl'
      }
    },    
  })
```

In **profile.html** I have following content that I needs to be dynamically updated -

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
  <h1 class="title">[THIS IS DYNAMIC CONTENT]</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable bar-subheader">
    <h1 class="title">[THIS TOO To BE MADE DYNAMIC]</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="profileContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

Let me know if is there any way in Ionic tags to control(dynamically control the content) so that if I visit, `profile.name` state it should update the header with name title, if I visit, `profile.address` state it should update the header with address title  so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

## Set a scope

In your controller set a scope like

```
$scope.usrName = 'bob';
```

In your html you can call that in your title like

```
<h1 class="title">{{usrName}}</h1>
```

Just make sure your ctrl is available.

Comment: It will not going to work as you can see that profile page is not having any controller associated with it, and I want to keep some common stuff in profile.html as headers are going to appear on my every next page

Comment: you have `controller: 'profileCtrl'`, set it in there.

Comment: yes, but I want to put my header code in profile.html page only and not in profile-basics.html page

Comment: Actually I have 3-4 nested states like - profile basics, profile search, profile matches etc, so my thought is to use header code only once in view ie profile.html and in controllers I can give the title and it with be less code and more genuine way of doing  a thing

Comment: I don't see why you can't still set the scope? profile should have the same header everywhere right? maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: try same..with $rootScope..!